# Can I use kafka to invoke microservices from the same family of microservices asynchronously?

Tags: apache-kafka, microservices, istio

This is the situation for managing distributed transactionality when we are working with a number of microservices to handle a request.

Let's say we have four microservices, each represented by four states, we can have a whole family of microservices for each state, so we have high availability at the microservice layer. Each microservice will not have its own database, I want each microservice to attack the same data cluster following the CQRS pattern.

In the layer above those microservices, I have a layer that acts as an orchestrator, that manages the transactional state of each request, each request will obviously have a unique identifier.

Now, when the cycle starts, I want the orchestrator to invoke only one of the A family micro-services, when that A family can potentially have as many A family docker containers as we see necessary, but I want only one to be selected to handle the request. I want to be able to invoke the microservice asynchronously, I don't want to use anything like synchronous REST, so I understand that I must use a subscriber publishing system, for example kafka. To give an example, I am talking as broadly as possible without being tied to any technology. I understand that each transactional state is going to be tied to a topic, let's say for state A, it would be called topicA and if we have several microservices to attend the transactional state A, at the end we would have as many topics as states and microservices of a family, that is, topicA-1, topicA-2,..., topicA-n, topicB-a, topicB-2,...,topicB-n,...topicD-1,topicD-2,...topicD-n. So I understand that in the end I need a load balancing between the orchestrator and the publisher subscriber layer to select the topic I'm going to send the message to. Each microservice will also have another channel to send the message to the orchestrator layer, only this time it will only be necessary to have one consumer shared by all the microservices in the orchestrator layer to listen to the response and update the status of each distributed transaction.

Is there a load balancer at the subscriber publisher level? Is there a product or recommended way to do it or would I have to do it from scratch? Is this the recommended way to manage distributed transactionality when I have an orchestrator class that manages the transactional status? What problems can I find by following this path that I propose?

Ideally, partitions can be created for each topic, so that one topic manages a transactional state corresponding to each microservice. Each partition within the topic would correspond to a microservice, so far so good, now, how could you do it dynamically? because potentially speaking there will be times when it is detected that only n microservices of one type are needed, at other times they may be more, less and that will require dynamically managing in the load balancer those sub-partitions in each topic, so that it can create them, delete them, assign that partition to a microservice, tell the controller class that it can use that partition to communicate asynchronously with that microservice, manage the health of that microservice and act accordingly?

Is there such a thing in the market? If possible open source, I would not like to reinvent the wheel.

Thank you for reading this far and excuse the length of the text.

Comment: Maybe you could add a diagram that helps to get a better understanding on what your proposal is about? what are exactly the layers and components involved?

In order to keep it simple, it sounds like you would need some partitioning, where the events/states/topics are partitioned in the same way that the microservices, in a  1-1 relation. Then your subscriber/publishing needs no concurrency control by construction. If topic/partition overloads and requires adding more microservices to be processed, you could add additional levels of partitioning, but always keeping that 1-1  relation.

Comment: I think that what I need is to follow this advice. https://link.medium.com/3fxEmZUII6

Comment: Partitioning topics is the key, but this behavior cannot be dinamically automatized. If I add or delete micro services listening to a topic, I would like to reasign dinamically those partitioned topics...

Comment: Maybe Apache Istio could do the job.